# Properly closing websocket on python

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm using websockets lib on python to create a websockets server in a custom thread:

```
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    async def listener(websocket, path):
        async for message in websocket:
            self.onMessage.emit(message)

    self._server=websockets.serve(listener, 'localhost', 8765)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self._server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()

    print("Finished...")
```

Now I want to stop this server cleanly, but it seems I'm missing something. From the docs, they state that to close the server the only thing I have to do is using something like this (This is a function in the custom thread class called from main thread):

```
def stop(self):
    self._server.ws_server.close()
    self._server.ws_server.wait_closed();
```

but the "Finished..." text is never printed.

am I misunderstanding the documentation or something?

Cheers.

Comment: Since `wait_closed` is a coroutine, you need to either `await` it or use `run_until_complete` to let it run its course.

Comment: Didn't no ticed it was a coroutine, anyway this is not the reason the loop doesn't ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after playing a little bit I finished accomplish a clean install using this:

```
async def _internalStop(self):
    self._server.ws_server.close()
    await self._server.ws_server.wait_closed()
    self._eventLoop.stop();
    while(self._eventLoop.is_running()):
        time.sleep(0.5)
    self._eventLoop.close();
    self._eventLoop=None;
```